# Using object properties in expressions?

Tags: .net, data-binding

I have a PHP background and I'm trying to learn .NET. I'm wondering about binding data.

If I have the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string name;
    public string testnaam;

}

Test nat = new Test();
nat.name = "blaat";
nat.testnaam = "blaat2";
```

Why can't I do this (or something like it):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="<% nat.name %>" />
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it entirely not possible to use object properties like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a client side button, i.e.

```
<input type="button" value="<%= buttonText %>" />
```

Then declare a public variable in your server side code

```
public string buttonText = "This is my button text";
```

The same applies to an object as long as it's public and instantiated correctly. Make sure the variable is defined as public, then instantiate it in your page_load:

```
person = new Person { FirstName = "Joe", Surname = "Bloggs" };
```

And in your markup:

```
<input type="button" value="<%= person.FirstName %>" />
```

Comment: But this only works when this is a property of the page class? Can't I use the properties of a separate class? Like `Test`, but in the application namespace?

Comment: I think I understand, but I'm still getting an error when doing this: `<input type="button" value="<%= nat.name %>" />` after doing this in the page_load: `Test nat = new Test();` With the same `Test` class as above with `public string name = "test"`;

Comment: Can you post your page_load function and variable declaration so I can take a look? If you're declaring `Test nat = new Test();` in your page_load then the problem is the scope of your variable, i.e. the variable only exists in the scope of your page_load function, not the page itself. You need to declare it like this:
 
`public Test nat; protected void page_load(...) { nat = new Test { name = "blaat", testnaam = "blaat2" }; }`

Comment: That's it! If I understand it correctly, the objects needs to be  declared in the page class to be accessible as an property of that class? And thus accessible by the page itself? Than why is it needed to instantiate the object in the Page_Load function? Why can't I instantiate it in the Page class?

Comment: I realize that I know the answer to my last comment: `public Test nat = new Test();`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="<% nat.name %>" />
```

Is that `asp:Button` is a *server side* control and that `<%%>` expand to `<script runat="server"></script>`. This would be invalid.

Comment: Oke, but if I use: '<input id="Button1" value="<% nat.name %>" />' ?

Comment: @MartinH - Sure, assuming there is a property or field `nat` that has been initialized correctly.

Comment: I instantiated the class Test in the Page_Load class, but I still get an exception:  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: The exception to the above is when you are [data binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) (usually as part of some data container):  `<asp:Button Text="<%# Eval(Container.DataItem) %>" ...`. Then you can include the shorthand within the control's property.

Comment: @KennethK. - Yes, but binding expressions are a different beast altogether.

Comment: @Oded Agreed, but I think it's worth knowing about. If MartinH sees an example of data binding, but we don't tell him what it means now, then he may wonder if what you said was accurate  :)

Comment: @Oded: But how do I get the property `nat.name` initialized correctly?

Comment: @MartinH - `Page_Load` is a method, not a class. You need a `nat` property in the code behind that is in scope for the page. The declaration would have to be outside of any method. Read up on [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).